# Make MediaWiki use accounts on my site?

Tags: php, asp.net, mediawiki

I have a site in ASP.NET and i thought it would be cool if i can redirect users to wiki.mysite.com. Now i would like to know if i can easily make MediaWiki recognize users logged into my site. I dont want any anonymous posters.

Is there a way to hook or have mediawiki use accounts/cookies from my site instead of using its own database/account system?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, there are a variety of hooks for things like this.  Perhaps you want [UserLoadFromSession](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:Hooks/UserLoadFromSession).  You might find [Extension:DNNAuthentication](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension:DNNAuthentication) or [Extension:OpenID](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension:OpenID) useful starting points.